# How to get specific fitted value of corresponding x in ycinterextra package in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I am new to R so please keep that in mind :)
I am currently using package ‘ycinterextra’ and interpolating yield curve with several methods. For example,

```
maturity<- c(1,2,5,10)
yield<- c(0.39,0.61,1.66,2.58)
t<-seq(from=min(maturity), to=max(maturity), by=0.01) 
yc <- ycinter(yM = yield, matsin = maturity, matsout = t, method="SW",typeres="rates")
fitted(yc)
```

I know how to get fitted(yc), but I don't know how to get one value for specific maturity. for example if I am interested in 4-year yield or 1.5-year yield? What I need is just one value that correspond to specific t (any).

Thansk in advance!

Comment: The package doesn't appear to implement `predict` or predict like feature.

Comment: I've noticed. For other methods (NS, SV, spline) it's easy to construct a function from extracted coefficients from yc, but for SW method it's not so easy for me. Do you have some idea how to resolve this because this method gives me pretty good curve for my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly and very old question, but here is what I think you should do. Simply match your value from `t` and find it from fitted values.

```
as.numeric(fitted(yc))[match(4.5,t)]
[1] 1.460163
```